# How embedding lookup works in Word2Vec

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to understand Word2Vec. For word input of 5x1 (one hot encoding) and hidden layer of 3 units.I have came across following information from famous sources. The first (monochrome) image says the first column will become the embedding vector when multiplying  3x 5 to 5 x 1 matrix while in 2nd image, 4th row is taken against 1 x 5 one hot encoding. This is confusing. The embedding lookup pics row or column is not understandable. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of custom intros to the word2vec algorithm online that, in my opinion, are quite unhelpful in what they choose to highlight.

So, if you're struggling with a particular one, I'd suggest moving on to some other. And if you have to go someplace else (like StackOverflow) to explain some *external* writeup, try to provide a link to the full original source as context for understanding what that particular author has adopted as their mental-model.

Further, if your true interest is in understanding actual word2vec implementation, studying working source code may be a better path than more abstract write-ups, for seeing what actually happens.

Although abstractly, you *can* think of a word-vector lookup as being the multiplication of a one-hot vector times a (count-of-vocabulary x count-of-dimensions) matrix, I've not seen popular implementations (like Google's original `word2vec.c` release, or the Python Gensim library) do exactly that. So learning that form can mislead when later using, or reviewing the source code of, or implementing real code.

Instead, implementations tend to use the word-token as a key to lookup a row-number inside some sort of `dict`/hashtable. (No one-hot vector is ever created – except abstractly, in the sense that a simple `int` can be thought of as representing the one-hot vector with a single one at that int index.)

Then, they use that row-number to access the word's vector, from a matrix that's better considered the "input weights" that lead to a hidden-layer, rather than any "hidden layer" itself. (The "hidden layer" activations, at least in 1:1 modes like skip gram, is then that vector itself.)

That is: despite the abstract description, in implementations, no multiplication occurs. An index-lookup occurs, then a simple row-access-by-that-index occurs, and then you've got a word's vector. (And yes, it's the same result as-f there'd been a one-hot multiplication - at least in a simple skip-gram mode, where the 'input' to the network is a single context word.)

To try to map to that diagram's top (monochrome) half: you have a 5-word vocabulary, where each word has 3 dimensions. The *columns* of that `w00 .. w24` table, with 0-based indexes {0,1,2,3,4} are the individual word-vectors. (This varies from most implementations I know, where individual word-vectors are the *rows* of the model's matrix.)

So, per the top (monochrome) half, you get the 3-dimensional word-vector for the 1st of 5 words by pulling the *column* that's `w[0][0] .. w[2][0]`: rows 0-2, column 0

In contrast, per the bottom (multicolor) half, you get the 3-dimensional word-vector for the 4th of 5 words by pulling the *row* that's `cell[3][0] to cell[3][2]`: rows 3, columns 0-2

The bottom diagram better fits the implementations I know. There, learned word-vectors – both the in-progress vectors grabbed for adjustment during training, & what's accessed at the end as final word-vectors – are more often stored as the *rows* of an "input weights" matrix.

That matrix *can be thought of* as a mapping from one-hot vectors to hidden-layer activations - but really isn't a "hidden layer" itself. And further: in a mode like "CBOW with averaging", the actual "hidden layer" activations are an *average* of multiple rows' values.

Of your 2 diagrams, the bottom better represents usual implementations – though again, usually no actual "multiplication by a one-hot" occurs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i again searched and found [this link](https://aegis4048.github.io/demystifying_neural_network_in_skip_gram_language_modeling#window_size) to be of somewhat help but even in this link, the input 8x1 becomes 1x8 in the later part which is confusing. Pl tell me if input is 8x1 and hidden is 3x1 then the weight matrix would be 8x3 or 3x8. This is very confusing.

Comment: The '8x3' 'input weights' shown there represents the 8 known words, of 3 dimensions each, in the full virtual neural network "at rest". Any particular training example in skip-gram would be just *one* context word, virtually a one-hot (8x1) sparse vector - but as I'd mentioned, implementations *don't* ever even bother to create such a vector. They just use an int index to mean 'word #3' (or whatever).

Comment: And I would again urge you to read source code, rather than various idiosyncratic explanations online, because in Gensim's default negative-sampling mode, its set of 'hidden to output weights' (called `syn1neg` in source code) is *also* just of dimensions 8x3 (8 possible predicted words, by the 3 dimensions of the hidden layer's activations) – not the '3x8' this abstract explanation declares. Either may be a reasonable way to *think* about it - but in practice there'll be whatever calcs/transposes required to get useful results in interpretable forms.

Comment: Thus, following concrete code-that-works may help reach understanding what's actually happening, in a consistent & applicable way, moreso than trying to match someone else's abstract description of the steps in *their* mental model.

Comment: if you can provide link to that code, this may seem naive but the problem is, there are too many code snippet an expert like you is only authority for me to point to a specific. i may end up following wrong code which may be implementation of some ones mental model. last help buddy

Comment: The original Google-released `word2vec.c` is reasonable real working code to read if you're comfortable with C code. The Gensim Python/Cython code was originally based on that same C code, and has grown with extra options/optimizations – but is still an example of a real working & widely-used implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i can work with C Code. God Bless.